# I want to replace some characters in file 1 and want to write the output of replaced characters into file 2 with Perl

Tags: perl

I have file `actual.out.tmp`, and I want to replace some characters and send the output to 
file `actual.out`. I tried the following code :

```
open(ACTUAL, "$tmpDir/data/actual_out.tmp");
my $pattern="";
while(<ACTUAL>)
{   
 $pattern .= $_;
}   
close(ACTUAL);
$pattern=~s/@[^[]*/@/g;
$rc= systemTestSetup::execute("touch $tmpDir/data/actual_out");
open(ACTUAL1, ">$tmpDir/data/actual_out");
print ACTUAL1 ;

close(ACTUAL1);
sleep(10);
```

Comment: What have you tried? You are aware that this is as simple as `perl -pe's/pattern/substitute/' <file1 >file2`?

Comment: open(ACTUAL, "$tmpDir/data/actual_out.tmp");
 my $pattern="";
 while(<ACTUAL>)
 { 
  $pattern .= $_;
         $pattern=~s/@[^[]*/@/g;
         print Actual ;
 } 
 close(ACTUAL);

Comment: That's not readable. If you need to add to your question, add to your question by editing it.

Comment: it is not writing to actual.out file

Comment: Pls suggest some help

Answer (score 0):

I believe the line `print ACTUAL1;` should be `print ACTUAL1 $pattern`, since that's where you did your search-and-replace (`$_` still has the last line of the original file in it, I think).

There may be other problems as well.